# What is Smart City in terms of GIS?

Tags: mapping

I heard of Smart Cities with surveillance on the streets etc.
But what does it mean for GIS?
Does anyone have a good example?

Comment: I notice that you have not yet taken the [tour] which will lead you into our [help/on-topic] and much advice on how to write questions suitable for our focussed Q&A format.